# preciso de ajuda no enum em java

Tags: java, persistência, enums

Estou migrando um aplicação desktop em delphi para java, e no delphi tem uma classe que persiste no banco os valores 00, 10, 20 e 30. Estou fazendo um enum em java para persistir os valores. Eu sei que, por anotação, tem como definir as estrategias de string  e ordinal , mas nenhuma delas me atende.

Oque eu tenho ate agora.

```
public enum Tipo {
    tipo("00"),
    tipo1("10"),
    tipo2("20"),
    tipo3("30");

    String valor;

    private Tipo(String valor) {
        this.valor=valor;
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }   
}
```

Gostaria de saber se estou no caminho ou se existe um melhor jeito, para criar esse enum?

Comment: Não adicione imagem do código, adicone o código em texto. Leitura recomendada: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui com esse código.

O enum ficou assim.

```
@Column(name="MOD_RECEPCAO", length=2)
        private String modeloRecepcao;
        public enum ModRecepcao{

            conferencia_recepicao("00"),
            conferencia_recepicao_armagenagem_Ulma("10"),
            conferencia_recepicao_puxada_armagenagem_Ulma("20"),
            conferencia_recepicao_armagenagem_total("30");

            private final String valor;

            private ModRecepcao(String valor){
                this.valor=valor;
            }

            //converão e verificação se nome da classe para valor
            public static String parseSet(String s) {
                for (ModRecepcao modelo: ModRecepcao.values()) {
                    if (s.equals(modelo.toString())) return modelo.getValor();
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Modelo invalido");
            }

            //convesão e verificação de valor para o nome da classe
            public static String parseGet(String s) {
                for (ModRecepcao modelo: ModRecepcao.values()) {
                    if(s == null){
                        return "";
                    }
                    if (s.equals(modelo.getValor())){
                        return modelo.toString();
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Modelo invalido");
            }

             public String getValor() {
                    return this.valor;
            }

        }

 get e set
public String getModeloRecepcao() {
            return ModRecepcao.parseGet(modeloRecepcao);
        }


        public void setModeloRecepcao(String modeloRecepcao) {
            this.modeloRecepcao = ModRecepcao.parseSet(modeloRecepcao);
        }
```

mais eu gostaria de algo mais elegante. se alguém tiver uma ideia me ajude por favor.

Comment: Esta é a solução? Se for outra duvida, você deve criar uma nova pergunta ou editar esta, este campo é somente para respostas.

Comment: E a que eu encontrei mais não a que eu quero, então gostaria muito saber se existe uma outra solução eu não ,pois preciso urgente dessa ajuda;por isso não criei uma nova pergunta.